# Inner Join Same Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have data below

[image]

What I need is something like this

[image]

Is this possible to get data like this?

I do some research and getting insight using lead / lag function, but the result was not expected, heres what I tried

```
SELECT Id, Username, Distributor, 
    LEAD(Id) OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY Id) AS IdNew,
    LEAD(Distributor) OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY Id) AS IdNew 
FROM UserDist
```

[image]

another try using dense_rank, still no luck

```
DROP Table IF EXISTS #Temp 
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Seq INT,
    Id INT,
    Username NVARCHAR(100),
    Distributor NVARCHAR(100)
)


INSERT INTO #Temp(Seq, Id, Username, Distributor)
select DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Username  ORDER BY IdDum) AS Seq,
Id, Username, Distributor
from UserDist

select * from #Temp A

Seq Id  Username    Distributor
1   1   Joe         RNN
1   1   Joe         CNN
1   1   Joe         SSN
2   2   Joe         DSS
2   2   Joe         DDK
3   4   Joe         GER
3   4   Joe         RIG
3   4   Joe         POL
3   4   Joe         MOD
1   3   Kelly       OPK
1   3   Kelly       DLC
2   5   Kelly       DERMA
2   5   Kelly       KOI
2   5   Kelly       DELL
```

Instead of like returning that i needed, it return redundant data

```
select * from #Temp A LEFT  JOIN #Temp B ON A.Username = B.Username AND A.Seq + 1 = B.Seq
WHERE A.Seq = 1 AND A.Username = 'Joe'


Seq Id  Username    Distributor Seq Id  Username    Distributor
1   1   Joe         RNN         2    4  Joe         DSS
1   1   Joe         RNN         2    5  Joe         DDK
1   2   Joe         CNN         2    4  Joe         DSS
1   2   Joe         CNN         2    5  Joe         DDK
1   3   Joe         SSN         2    4  Joe         DSS
1   3   Joe         SSN         2    5  Joe         DDK
```

Comment: What is the criteria which defines that the row #1 matches the row #4 and not the row #5? Physical ordering doesn't fit.. PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/DQpjgQDV

Comment: Your `Id` number is not unique. Therefore the window functions you're using to sort on it, are going to nondeterminsitically (pseudo-randomly) sort the data. E.g. if you had 3 t-shirts with different logos on each of them, and they were all colored red, and someone asked you to sort them by color, which t-shirt would come first? That's what you're asking the SQL Server Engine to do. What is the unique key for your data that can be concretely sorted on?